# i want to check if a word not exists in a array php

Tags: php, arrays

I want to check if some word already exists in a array, for example 'kijken'.

This word does not exists in the array and I want to add it.

How do I make a check if the word exists?

My array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => vegen
    [1] => veeg
)
Array
(
    [0] => staan
    [1] => sta
)
```

Comment: SO **is not a free coding resource** I'll tell you how to code it if you tell me how to **win the lottery**

Comment: I did try it with in_array but can't write the goog code to do the job

Comment: @RiggsFolly It is when there's a dupe there Smokey ;-) (closed and gone to dinner)

Answer (score 3):

The already classic function:

```
function in_array_r($needle, $haystack, $strict = false) {
  foreach ($haystack as $item) {
    if (($strict ? $item === $needle : $item == $needle) || (is_array($item) && in_array_r($needle, $item, $strict))) {
        return true;
    }
}

return false;
}

$term = 'kijken';

if ( in_array_r($term,$yourarray) == true ) {
     //do stuff
} else {
    echo $term.' not in array';
}
```

Comment: thanks for this code and i will try if it work for me

Comment: can't guarantee we'll be seeing a green tick next to the answer, but let's cross our fingers ;-) (given their track record). I guess they don't know how Stack rolls.

Comment: Doesn't really matter. Glad to be of help. I remember being in this position once upon a time. :)

Comment: @PeterNoble No doubt Peter and quite noble on your part (edit: no pun intended). However, many a time OP's come back and say *"it doesn't work...."* how many times the guys on Stack see that; countless. Let's just hope it doesn't open up a can of worms for you ;-) But I'll upvote.

Comment: Cheers. As it happens, I have a couple of free hours, so no harm done. :)

Comment: @PeterNoble No pun intended on your family name Peter; sorry.. I actually didn't even notice lol

Comment: @Fred-ii- Lol. Good one. No harm done, aside from a good laugh. :)

Comment: @PeterNoble Glad to see someone with a sense of humour :) *cheers*

Comment: Thanks Peter it works great. Thanks for your help with this :)